# Site design idea

Tags: discussion

After the recent debate about the site design, I was wondering what would work. What about the blackboard as a background, but with paper "stuck" on so that all the text etc has a white background. So that you only see the blackboard at the edges, like the Home Improvement design, just with more rugged paper and a blackboard instead of blue blueprint background.

Just a suggestion, because i thought the blackboard design **looked** good, but was impractical, which outweighed the looks.

Comment: I plan to do another design for Physics.SE down the road. If we choose real life visual metaphors, then they should make sense. No one sticks papers on a blackboard, so I'm not sure if that will work. I'm open for a light theme completely. I think Math.SE has a good academic theme.

Comment: @Jin: good to know that we're still on the list for some time in the future ;) I agree that math.SE has a very elegant theme - if they weren't already using it, I think that theme (or at least the colors) would have been a great choice for this site.

Answer (score 5):

I disagree. Unless someone convinces me otherwise, I think blackboard just as a frame would look horrible.

For me a completely light design with just white background and decent colors is all I need. What we have now isn't bad but colors could definitely be improved (don't ask me how though) and I also dislike the squares.

Comment: The squares actually get me a bit confused… on the other hand, i did like the original design. ;-) So, to quote a famous philosopher-of-sound: "You can't always get what you want…" 8-)